# Pandas Groupby Season and Year Average Column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, average

i have a df "ncData" that looks like this below and I'm trying to group the data by season (Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn) and take the mean of the wind speed  and power column for the months of each season of each year for each windfarm_name. Here is the first few lines of ncData:

```
ncData.head(2)
Out[432]: 
     site_name windfarm_name region_name                      time  \
4055     REDCK    Red Creek   Northeast 2019-12-28 20:00:00+00:00   
4056     REDCK    Red Creek   Northeast 2019-12-28 19:00:00+00:00   

      wind_speed    power       Dates     Hours  year month day  Season  
4055     5.89692  23.9702  2019-12-28  20:00:00  2019    12  28  Winter  
4056     4.75525  13.8225  2019-03-28  19:00:00  2019     3  28  Spring
```

I have tried things like:

```
ncData.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Season', freq='1Y'),pd.Grouper(key='windfarm_name')]).mean()
```

with this error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 
'Index'
```

and, i've tried like this:

```
ncData.groupby(['Season','windfarm_name'],freq='1Y')['wind_speed'].mean()
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
         time       windfarm_name  season         wind_speed power
0    1991          Red Creek      winter         3.917762   8.276560
1    1991          Red Creek      spring         3.046854   0.132271
2    1991          Red Creek      summer         3.737426   6.799836
3    1991          Red Creek      autumn         3.870350   4.010200
4    1991         Oasis Wind      winter         2.955412   2.898962
5    1991         Oasis Wind      spring         2.707168   0.076643
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it

```
ncData.groupby(['year', 'windfarm_name', 'Season'])['wind_speed', 'power'].mean()
```

---

Notice you can do without spliting the time column into year, month, day. Just make sure it is of type `DateTime` and

```
ncData.groupby([ncData['time'].month, 'windfarm_name', 'Season'])['wind_speed', 'power'].mean()
```

Comment: You may need to convert Season to a (sorted) Categorical type, in order to sort by seasonal order (winter, spring, ...) and not lexicographical order.